PKIX path building failed - unable to find valid certification path to requested target - AWS EC2
I have two EC2 instances in the same VPN and subnet.
Instance one is running Keycloak in a Docker container in production mode. To configure HTTPS, I generated a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL with the following commands:
Generate the private key:
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048

Generate the certificate:
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out certificate.crt -days 365

Generate the .p12 file:
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey private.key -out certificate.p12 -name keycloak -password pass:changeit

Keycloak's Dockerfile is configured to use the .p12 file.
On the second EC2 instance, I imported the .crt file into a truststore:
keytool -importcert -file certificate.crt -keystore truststore.jks -alias keycloak-cert

From the second EC2 instance, I can successfully use curl with the certificate to connect to Keycloak, retrieve an access token, and create a user using the access token.
In my Spring Boot microservice (which works fine in dev mode without HTTPS), I imported both the truststore.jks and the certificate.crt into the resources folder (I imported both to test each option).
I added the following configuration to the application.yml file:
javax:
  net:
    ssl:
      trustStore: classpath:truststore.jks
      trustStorePassword: changeit

I also tried running the Spring Boot application container with the following docker run command:
sudo docker run -d --name <service-name> \
-p 8080:8080 \
-v <certs_folder_path>:/app/certs \
-e JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/certs/certificate.crt" \
<image>

Additionally, I tested using the .jks located on the EC2 instance, providing its path in the application.yml file, but no matter what I try, I keep getting the following error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] with root cause
    
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:271) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:256) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1302) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1138) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:206) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:302) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:494) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:152) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:115) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy153.grantToken(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:99) ~[keycloak-admin-client-21.0.1.jar:21.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:75) ~[keycloak-admin-client-21.0.1.jar:21.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:70) ~[keycloak-admin-client-21.0.1.jar:21.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52) ~[keycloak-admin-client-21.0.1.jar:21.0.1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:767) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:491) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:152) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:115) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy161.search(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.userservice.service.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.userservice.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]

I also want to add that in the spring boot application I use Keycloak admin client to create the users etc. with this configuration (working on dev):
public Keycloak getKeycloakInstance() {

    if (keycloakInstance == null) {
        keycloakInstance = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                .realm(realm)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
    }

    return keycloakInstance;
}

